# Move commits to new branch prior to push

Tags: git

I have a half dozen commits I want in a new branch but I have not pushed them yet. Is there an easy way to rebase them prior to doing the push?

Comment: Do you want to push the commits you have made to a different branch than they are currently on? For example, do you want to push the commits on your local `dev` branch to the remote `origin`, but name the branch `new-dev-branch`? I am confused by your use of 'rebase' here.

Comment: Yes, but you need to be more specific.  Ideally, you might draw a pictorial representation of the commit-tree you have now, vs the one you want to have before you do the `git push`.  Start with `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` to get "what you have now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push a commit to a specific branch on a remote using the following command:

```
git push <remote> <commitish>:<destination branch>
```

For example:

```
# Push your current HEAD to a branch called `new-branch` on `origin`
git push origin HEAD:new-branch
```

Another option is to make a new branch and just push that:

```
# Make a new branch, named `new-branch`, from your current HEAD, then push it
git branch new-branch
git push origin new-branch
```

In both these scenarios, you will still be on your original branch that you started from, with the same set of commits as you started with.